# Radio Button information pass with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code which I use to post variables with ajax.

I am passing a radio button, and it takes one value, I mean it doesn't take the selected values, it takes one by default.

Here are my codes:
HTML

```
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="1" /> Mbyllur<br />
<input type="radio"  id="status" name="status" value="0" /> Hapur<br />
```

Javascript

```
 var js_status = $("#status").val();
```

It takes the first value. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

PHP

```
$postStatus = filter_var($_POST["postStatus"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've given them both the same ID. When you're searching it by ID, which one is it to reference?

You want something like this:

```
var js_status = $('input[name=status]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting the radio button with an id of 'status' which will always be the first button. .val() will only give you the value of 1.

What you're looking for is the current value of the CHECKED radio button. Like below.

```
$('input:radio[name=status]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Id has to be unique in your page

2) If you want the selected option use ':checked' :

```
var js_status = $('input[name="status"]:checked').val();
```

Edit : [link](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var status = $("#status input[type='radio']:checked").val();

or 

var status = $("input[type='radio'][name='status']:checked").val();
```